# Click Events in Modal Popup Extender

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I have a ASP.NET page where a modal popup extender is shown when we click on a link button...There is a submit button in the Modalpopup extender which inserts the data into a DB table.... the proble is there are field validators for the textboxes in the modalpopup extender...for which validation is required...

After entering the values, in the textboxes the submit is working for the second click, but not on the first click...

Can u please help me over.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be handy if you could post the code you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ValidationGroup for the validators and for the Submit button in the popup to the same value, "PopupValidationGroup" or something like that.